# Maintain php object state

Tags: php, object

My php code creates a "School" object which is (among other functions) able to return several forms which are being ,on submit, handled by php. 
Thru one of these forms i'm able to add a "SchoolClass" object to a array in the "School" object but it seems that the "School" object is recreated at some point after i add the "SchoolClass" object. This re-creation makes the array of "SchoolClass" disappear.

The functions that returns the forms are static, but the functions where "SchoolClass" objects are added to the array are not static; ("School::ShowStudentForm() and School->RegisterSchoolClass($class)")

Both the class definition and the php-script which handles the form after submit is in the same file(index.php). I had the idea that keeping both the class code and the form handling code in the same file would do the trick, but it did not make a change.

Question 1: how do i maintain the "School" object for as long as i need it?
Question 2: is it ok to create a class with only static methods and write the data directly to a file or database to avoid the whole problem or just skip the whole object approach and just use "normal" functions?

Yes, this problem is probably encounterd before and therefore also answered before but i have not been able to find a answer which i understand.

Comment: Are you referring to preserving data through multiple HTML form pages?

Comment: If i understand your question the answer is only one form at the time. But there are several forms which can be called from "School"

Answer (score 0):

OK....i figured it out.
I can use the $_SESSION variable to store it.

Now i do like this in the start of the page:

```
$school = null;
if(!isset($_SESSION["school"]))
{ 
$school = new School; 
$_SESSION["school"] = $school;
echo "New school <br>";   
} else {
$school = $_SESSION["school"];
}
```